# Difference between docker-compose and manual commands

Tags: docker, fig, docker-compose

#### What I'm trying to do

I want to run a yesod web application in one docker container, linked to a postgres database in another docker container.

#### What I've tried

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
/
    api/
        Dockerfile
    database/
        Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
```

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
database:
    build: database
api:
    build: api
    command: .cabal/bin/yesod devel # dev setting
    environment:
        - HOST=0.0.0.0
        - PGHOST=database
        - PGPORT=5432
        - PGUSER=postgres
        - PGPASS
        - PGDATABASE=postgres
    links:
        - database
    volumes:
        - api:/home/haskell/
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

Running `sudo docker-compose up` fails either to start the api container at all or, just as often, with the following error:

```
api_1      | Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
api_1      | yesod: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
personal_api_1 exited with code 1
```

If, however, I run `sudo docker-compose database up &` then start up the api container without using compose but instead using

```
sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 -itv /home/me/projects/personal/api/:/home/haskell --link personal_database_1:database personal_api /bin/bash
```

I can `export` the environment variables being set up in the `docker-compose.yml` file then manually run `yesod devel` and visit my site successfully on localhost.

Finally, I obtain a third different behaviour if I run `sudo docker-compose run api` on its own. This seems to start successfully but I can't access the page in my browser. By running `sudo docker-compose run api /bin/bash` I've been able to explore this container and I can confirm the environment variables being set in `docker-compose.yml` are all set correctly.

#### Desired behaviour

I would like to get the result I achieve from running the database in the background then manually setting the environment in the api container's shell simply by running `sudo docker-compose up`.

#### Question

Clearly the three different approaches I'm trying do slightly different things. But from my understanding of docker and docker-compose I would expect them to be essentially equivalent. Please could someone explain how and why they differ and, if possible, how I might achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error-message suggests the API container is expecting input from the command-line, which expects a TTY to be present in your container.

In your "manual" start, you tell docker to create a TTY in the container via the `-t` flag (`-itv` is shorthand for `-i -t -v`), so the API container runs successfully.

To achieve the same in docker-compose, you'll have to add a `tty` key to the API service in your `docker-compose.yml` and set it to `true`;

```
database:
    build: database
api:
    build: api
    tty: true # <--- enable TTY for this service
    command: .cabal/bin/yesod devel # dev setting
```